# printing each letter of string same number of times as number of letters

Tags: python

I am trying to make this function so that it prints each letter of the string, the number of times the same of number of letters in the string. so for example if the string was  'hi' , then the output of the function would be:

hh

ii

(each letters on separate lines like above)
however my code only prints 'ii' for the above example and I don't quite know why.

```
def vertical_strings(string):
    """takes a string and prints each letter on new line repeating each letter for length of word"""

    num = len(string)
    for char in string:
        new = char * num
    return new
print(vertical_strings('hi'))
```

Comment: you only return the last item in your loop in your current structure, why return any thing at all if the goal is to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def vertical_strings(string):
    """takes a string and prints each letter on new line repeating each letter for length of word"""

    num = len(string)
    for char in string:
        new = char * num
        print new
vertical_strings('hi')
```

You just have to make minor tweaks in your code

- Since you need to print, have the print on each iteration of the code

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the result for last letter only, try using a list of all letters repeated instead, then join the list's elements by a newline (`\n`) character:

```
def vertical_strings(string):
    num = len(string)
    new = []
    for char in string:
        new.append(char * num)
    return '\n'.join(new)

print(vertical_strings('hi'))
```

Output:

```
hh
ii
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there should also be a provision to capture unique letters only from the given string. My solution here emphasizes with a palindrome `mom` that there exists two unique character and there should be only *two lines* of output. Please check it out and give your feedback.

```
def vertical_strings(string):

    return [x*len(string) for x in list(set(string))]

[print(x) for x in vertical_strings('mom')]
```

Output:

```
mmm
ooo
```